# ANDROID share to facebook, twitter etc using share intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, share

I search through the web and found this sharing to facebook, twitter or email by using the share intent. This share intent is it suppose to have those facebook, twitter icon there to select for sharing? When i run in emulator, it writes no application can run this action. Is it the sharing cannot be run in emulator or my code is not completely done.

**Below is my code**

```
btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("plain/text");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "This is the text that will be shared.");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                        "Share via"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would suggest reading some basic about how the intent works in android http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: these intent will work on mobile device if there will facebook app & twitter app install already.

Answer (score 3):

The emulator has no Apps installed that can handle the share Intent. Therefore no App will be shown. If you don't have a Android device at hand you could try to download the Amazon Appstore or the [Androidpit](http://www.androidpit.com/) market application to your emulator and install sharing apps through this markets.

Comment: I installed into the real device but when i click the share button. There is only gmail and skype in the option but facebook and twitter application is already installed in my tablet.